# Generated files look different from the example

Tags: go, grpc, protoc

please help me. The below is given in .../gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.proto

==============================================

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.helloworld";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

======================================================

Then, i compiled to get a Go code

```
>> protoc  helloworld.proto   --go_out=plugins=:.
```

The generated code is below, but it looks quite different from /gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.pb.go

=======

```
It has these top-level messages:
    HelloRequest
    HelloReply
*/
package helloworld

import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"

import (
    context "golang.org/x/net/context"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ context.Context
var _ grpc.ClientConn

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ = proto.Marshal

// The request message containing the user's name.
type HelloRequest struct {
    Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name" json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func (m *HelloRequest) Reset()         { *m = HelloRequest{} }
func (m *HelloRequest) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*HelloRequest) ProtoMessage()    {}

// The response message containing the greetings
type HelloReply struct {
    Message string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=message" json:"message,omitempty"`
}

func (m *HelloReply) Reset()         { *m = HelloReply{} }
func (m *HelloReply) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*HelloReply) ProtoMessage()    {}

func init() {
}

// Client API for Greeter service

type GreeterClient interface {
    // Sends a greeting
    SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *HelloRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*HelloReply, error)
}

type greeterClient struct {
    cc *grpc.ClientConn
}

func NewGreeterClient(cc *grpc.ClientConn) GreeterClient {
    return &greeterClient{cc}
}

func (c *greeterClient) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *HelloRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*HelloReply, error) {
    out := new(HelloReply)
    err := grpc.Invoke(ctx, "/helloworld.Greeter/SayHello", in, out, c.cc, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

// Server API for Greeter service

type GreeterServer interface {
    // Sends a greeting
    SayHello(context.Context, *HelloRequest) (*HelloReply, error)
}

func RegisterGreeterServer(s *grpc.Server, srv GreeterServer) {
    s.RegisterService(&_Greeter_serviceDesc, srv)
}

func _Greeter_SayHello_Handler(srv interface{}, ctx context.Context, codec grpc.Codec, buf []byte) (interface{}, error) {
    in := new(HelloRequest)
    if err := codec.Unmarshal(buf, in); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    out, err := srv.(GreeterServer).SayHello(ctx, in)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

var _Greeter_serviceDesc = grpc.ServiceDesc{
    ServiceName: "helloworld.Greeter",
    HandlerType: (*GreeterServer)(nil),
    Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
        {
            MethodName: "SayHello",
            Handler:    _Greeter_SayHello_Handler,
        },
    },
    Streams: []grpc.StreamDesc{},
}
```

=============================================

i attached the file given in /gopath/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.pb.go

====================================================

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: helloworld.proto

package helloworld

import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
import fmt "fmt"
import math "math"

import (
    context "golang.org/x/net/context"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ = proto.Marshal
var _ = fmt.Errorf
var _ = math.Inf

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the proto package it is being compiled against.
// A compilation error at this line likely means your copy of the
// proto package needs to be updated.
const _ = proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion2 // please upgrade the proto package

// The request message containing the user's name.
type HelloRequest struct {
    Name                 string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func (m *HelloRequest) Reset()         { *m = HelloRequest{} }
func (m *HelloRequest) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*HelloRequest) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*HelloRequest) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_helloworld_71e208cbdc16936b, []int{0}
}
func (m *HelloRequest) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_HelloRequest.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *HelloRequest) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_HelloRequest.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (dst *HelloRequest) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_HelloRequest.Merge(dst, src)
}
func (m *HelloRequest) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_HelloRequest.Size(m)
}
func (m *HelloRequest) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_HelloRequest.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_HelloRequest proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *HelloRequest) GetName() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Name
    }
    return ""
}

// The response message containing the greetings
type HelloReply struct {
    Message              string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=message,proto3" json:"message,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func (m *HelloReply) Reset()         { *m = HelloReply{} }
func (m *HelloReply) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*HelloReply) ProtoMessage()    {}
func (*HelloReply) Descriptor() ([]byte, []int) {
    return fileDescriptor_helloworld_71e208cbdc16936b, []int{1}
}
func (m *HelloReply) XXX_Unmarshal(b []byte) error {
    return xxx_messageInfo_HelloReply.Unmarshal(m, b)
}
func (m *HelloReply) XXX_Marshal(b []byte, deterministic bool) ([]byte, error) {
    return xxx_messageInfo_HelloReply.Marshal(b, m, deterministic)
}
func (dst *HelloReply) XXX_Merge(src proto.Message) {
    xxx_messageInfo_HelloReply.Merge(dst, src)
}
func (m *HelloReply) XXX_Size() int {
    return xxx_messageInfo_HelloReply.Size(m)
}
func (m *HelloReply) XXX_DiscardUnknown() {
    xxx_messageInfo_HelloReply.DiscardUnknown(m)
}

var xxx_messageInfo_HelloReply proto.InternalMessageInfo

func (m *HelloReply) GetMessage() string {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Message
    }
    return ""
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterType((*HelloRequest)(nil), "helloworld.HelloRequest")
    proto.RegisterType((*HelloReply)(nil), "helloworld.HelloReply")
}

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var _ context.Context
var _ grpc.ClientConn

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the grpc package it is being compiled against.
const _ = grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion4

// GreeterClient is the client API for Greeter service.
//
// For semantics around ctx use and closing/ending streaming RPCs, please refer to https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.NewStream.
type GreeterClient interface {
    // Sends a greeting
    SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *HelloRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*HelloReply, error)
}

type greeterClient struct {
    cc *grpc.ClientConn
}

func NewGreeterClient(cc *grpc.ClientConn) GreeterClient {
    return &greeterClient{cc}
}

func (c *greeterClient) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *HelloRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*HelloReply, error) {
    out := new(HelloReply)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/helloworld.Greeter/SayHello", in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

// GreeterServer is the server API for Greeter service.
type GreeterServer interface {
    // Sends a greeting
    SayHello(context.Context, *HelloRequest) (*HelloReply, error)
}

func RegisterGreeterServer(s *grpc.Server, srv GreeterServer) {
    s.RegisterService(&_Greeter_serviceDesc, srv)
}

func _Greeter_SayHello_Handler(srv interface{}, ctx context.Context, dec func(interface{}) error, interceptor grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor) (interface{}, error) {
    in := new(HelloRequest)
    if err := dec(in); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if interceptor == nil {
        return srv.(GreeterServer).SayHello(ctx, in)
    }
    info := &grpc.UnaryServerInfo{
        Server:     srv,
        FullMethod: "/helloworld.Greeter/SayHello",
    }
    handler := func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return srv.(GreeterServer).SayHello(ctx, req.(*HelloRequest))
    }
    return interceptor(ctx, in, info, handler)
}

var _Greeter_serviceDesc = grpc.ServiceDesc{
    ServiceName: "helloworld.Greeter",
    HandlerType: (*GreeterServer)(nil),
    Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
        {
            MethodName: "SayHello",
            Handler:    _Greeter_SayHello_Handler,
        },
    },
    Streams:  []grpc.StreamDesc{},
    Metadata: "helloworld.proto",
}

func init() { proto.RegisterFile("helloworld.proto", fileDescriptor_helloworld_71e208cbdc16936b) }

var fileDescriptor_helloworld_71e208cbdc16936b = []byte{
    // 175 bytes of a gzipped FileDescriptorProto
    0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xff, 0xe2, 0x12, 0xc8, 0x48, 0xcd, 0xc9,
    0xc9, 0x2f, 0xcf, 0x2f, 0xca, 0x49, 0xd1, 0x2b, 0x28, 0xca, 0x2f, 0xc9, 0x17, 0xe2, 0x42, 0x88,
    0x28, 0x29, 0x71, 0xf1, 0x78, 0x80, 0x78, 0x41, 0xa9, 0x85, 0xa5, 0xa9, 0xc5, 0x25, 0x42, 0x42,
    0x5c, 0x2c, 0x79, 0x89, 0xb9, 0xa9, 0x12, 0x8c, 0x0a, 0x8c, 0x1a, 0x9c, 0x41, 0x60, 0xb6, 0x92,
    0x1a, 0x17, 0x17, 0x54, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x4e, 0xa5, 0x90, 0x04, 0x17, 0x7b, 0x6e, 0x6a, 0x71, 0x71,
    0x62, 0x3a, 0x4c, 0x11, 0x8c, 0x6b, 0xe4, 0xc9, 0xc5, 0xee, 0x5e, 0x94, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0x92, 0x5a,
    0x24, 0x64, 0xc7, 0xc5, 0x11, 0x9c, 0x58, 0x09, 0xd6, 0x25, 0x24, 0xa1, 0x87, 0xe4, 0x02, 0x64,
    0xcb, 0xa4, 0xc4, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x14, 0xe4, 0x54, 0x2a, 0x31, 0x38, 0x19, 0x70, 0x49, 0x67, 0xe6,
    0xeb, 0xa5, 0x17, 0x15, 0x24, 0xeb, 0xa5, 0x56, 0x24, 0xe6, 0x16, 0xe4, 0xa4, 0x16, 0x23, 0xa9,
    0x75, 0xe2, 0x07, 0x2b, 0x0e, 0x07, 0xb1, 0x03, 0x40, 0x5e, 0x0a, 0x60, 0x4c, 0x62, 0x03, 0xfb,
    0xcd, 0x18, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x0f, 0xb7, 0xcd, 0xf2, 0xef, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
}
```

============================================

Please, help me for why I have got different code. I have checked my current version of protoc

```
>>protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.1
```

Comment: Did you install protoc-gen-go from the homebrew or the official repository?

Answer (score 0):

The generated code is dependent on what version of `protoc`, `grpc` and `protoc-gen-go` you have installed.

Please run:

```
go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

The `go get -u` will force the libraries to update even if you already have an existing version.

**NOTE**: The question of what versions of things do I have installed (especially `protoc`) can plague you with an enterprise/long-running project. I highly recommend using an automation strategy that will generate the files for you and check them into your repo so that you know what version generated your files.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Obviously, i did

Comment: go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

Comment: even i did "reinstalling Golang" and clear all files inside "GOPATH". Then i installed all required files again.

Comment: >>protoc --version

Comment: libprotoc 3.6.1

Comment: very strange, i just followed all instruction in grpc-go tutorial

Comment: What SHAs do you have both of the previously mentioned repos?

Comment: sorry, i do not understand your question. I am not professional at Ubuntu. What do you mean SHAs ?

Comment: I installed protoc to the local directory, and added the path to .profile

Comment: >> export PATH=$PATH:/home/shan/protoc3/bin

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will do help:

```
protoc file.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

// Note:-

For changing the proto buffer file name use:

```
option go_package = "example_newpb";
package example;
```